# Veblen's theorem for digraphs

Tags: graph-theory

Here is another problem from Bondy/Murty: Prove that

> A directed graph admits a decomposition into directed cycles if and only if it is even.

Here a directed graph is *even* if all its vertices have the same in- and out-degree. This is the digraph-version of Veblen's theorem which is proved by induction in the book. I don't see how I can "convert" that proof into a proof for digraphs, and I can't come up with anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Can you do it by induction?  Say the graph has an edge.  Then at least one vertex $v$ has outdegree ≥ 1.  (Why?) So start at $v$ and walk until you come back to $v$.  (Prove this must happen.)  At this point you have found a cycle.  Remove this cycle.  If the graph has no more edges, you are done; otherwise, repeat.

Comment: I get it now, thanks!

Comment: Related answer: [How to prove $G$ is Eulerian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685602/how-to-prove-g-is-eulerian/746689#746689)

Comment: Note that when finding a cycle like this you don't necessarily come back to $v$ itself, but you return to some vertex you have already visited.

Comment: @funda This question asks about graphs where every vertex has outdegree equal to its indegree. In such a graph, what you suggested is impossible.

Comment: If we take the graph on vertices $1,2$ and $3$ with edges $(1,2), (2,3), (2,1),(3,2)$, your walk might do: $1,2,3,2$, and so the first _simple_ cycle you find is $2,3,2$.

Comment: I guess nowhere it says the cycles have to be simple, but then in your algorithm you should mention that you don't walk over already visited edges.

Comment: I didn't say to take the first simple cycle. I said "walk until you come back to $v$". Your example doesn't do this.